# Sqlite / Select list of constant strings as rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

The following SQLite query provides a list of 2 static strings (one per row)

```
SELECT 'somestring' as id
UNION 
SELECT 'someotherstring' as id
```

Result

```
id
---
somestring
someotherstring
```

Is there a shorter way to get the same result, because I will have 100+ rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `values()`:

```
with cte (id) as (
      select v.*
      from (values ('somestring'), ('someotherstring')) v
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `VALUES` inside a cte:

```
WITH cte(col) AS (VALUES ('somestring'), ('someotherstring'))
SELECT col FROM cte
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e72f0667baee9402eade53643040fc02).